# What is the proper golang workflow for developing locally and pushing to github?

Tags: go

What is the proper workflow to develop locally and push golang code to github?  Before the code is pushed to github, I won't be able to reference those libraries in commands and I would prefer not to push half-baked code.

If I run go build, that does not install the module.  Similarly, if I run go install, I don't see any additional files created under my ~/go directory.  It is only when I commit my changes and push to github followed by doing a go get -u github.com ... that I see the packages being installed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I simply needed to follow the directions here:

My workspace was not in the default location, no did I override the GOPATH ... and so that caused some grief.

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'replace' directive in your application go.mod file to specify modules that are local:

```
replace example.com/original/import/path => /your/forked/import/path
```

See: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive